# Finding the probability of the given function

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

The probability mass function is
\begin{array}{c|cccccccc}
x    & -3 & -1 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 5 & 8\\\hline
f(x) &  .1 & .2 & .15 & .2 & .1 & .15 & .05 & .05
\end{array}

I need to find:
$P(X=-3/X\leq0)$ and $P(X\geq3/X\geq0)$.
The answers are $2/9$ and $5/11$, respectively. How do I get them cause I am confused about $3/X$ thing...

Comment: I suspect that this is the less popular notation for $X=-3\mid X\leq 0$. Does that make more sense? The bar $\mid$  is read "given".

Comment: Thank you Max. It makes sense now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the basic formulas of conditional probability, for the first one, we obtain

$$P(X=-3\mid X \le 0)=\frac{P(X=-3 \text{ AND } X \le 0)}{P(X\le 0)}=\frac{P(X=-3)}{P(X \le 0)}=\frac{0.10}{.45}=\frac{2}{9}$$

Now can you apply the formula to the second one?

Answer (score 2):

As said in the comments, this is saying "What's the probability of $X$ being $-3$ given that $X\leq 0$".

This has a more standard notation: $P(X= -3 \mid X\geq 0)$, with '$\mid$' instead of '$/$'.